Get more information about "Daemons using outdated libraries" "Which services should be restarted?" pop-up
After apt install of some packages on debian, I get this window

(this is from a different SO question, not mine, but exactly the same window.)
I want to know more information. What are the "outdated libraries"; which is the old version, which is the new version? How to see more information about what are the "outdated libraries"? I am looking at the package dependency through "apt-cache depends" and I don't see any outdated library.
I just want to see more details before deciding, if it's worth restarting.

It seems this pop-up is run by needrestart tool.
All that needs to be done to display more details is to run (in a different terminal)
sudo needrestart -v -r l
which will list the details about the libraries, that are outdated.

and it's worth noting that most of the time when this happens, it's an update to glibc, or to libopenssl/libcrypto, as these are very pervasively used libraries :)

I was confused why was it libc when it was a go code (which doesn't depend on libc)... but the go code actually ran a child process which did use libc. And needrestart is smart enough to know that!
